# Почему Stack Overflow на Русском нет в топе сайтов на главной stackexchange.com?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, stackexchange

https://stackexchange.com/

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на https://stackexchange.com/sites мы есть:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На первом сортирую по трафику (vsits/day), а на втором по количеству вопросов

Comment: @avp по трафику математика на 7.

Comment: По вопросам на 6-м, а по visits/day где-то на 26-м

Comment: @avp всё равно странно как-то.

Comment: Это же top-network-sites во  вкладке real-time? В центре все прыгает в ритме real-time, а справа (то что вы показали), наверное какой-то момент из истории

Comment: @avp нет, в боковой панели справа снизу.

Comment: Если нажать там view all, то показывает текущую картину с сортировкой по visits/day. Предполагаю, что показанная вами это ее топ в каком-то прошлом

Comment: На MSE обсуждение: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324207/260198

Comment: Мне это напомнило другую [ситуацию](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299752/339911).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ они просто не любят локализованные сайты :D

Comment: @Suvitruf не понимают что там написано.

Comment: @Suvitruf А почему вы приняли ответ, который по сути никак не отвечает вопрос? Он похож на отписку "потому что гладиолус".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov потому что большего от них не добьёшься.

Comment: @Suvitruf Ну не факт, я бы попробовал.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну, формально, нас там нет, т.к. по формуле SOru не попадает в топ. А вот почему такой сортировки нет на странице `/sites` - это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [ответу Адама](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324210/260198), сортировка на главной - это сортировка по умолчанию. Формула:

```
((TotalQs + (TotalAs / 3)) * PercentAnswered / 100) + TotalUsers + VisitsPerDay
```

И её почему-то не смогли использовать на странице https://stackexchange.com/sites.